# Gremlin find shortest path and inspect each vertex along it for specific edge types

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm learing Gremlin and trying to find a way to traverse from a given vertex to another along a path and "locating" each edge of a type and the associated node.

This is a basic representation of the graph I'm working with:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to find a way to traverse from a **station** vertex to another along **travelsTo** edges and if any **announcedOn** edges are encountered along the way then gather up all **announcement** vertecies along the path:
[image]

In the example above I want to end up with two announcement elements in a list with their properties. If possible I'd also want to return the path taken to retrieve them as the final graph will have many different ways to get from station A to station B. Basically, I'd like to follow the path and find all **announcement** vertecies that are encountered.

I can relatively easily traverse the path using `repeat()` and `.path()` like this:

```
g.V()
    .has("station", "code", "ABC")
    .repeat(out("travelsTo").simplePath())
    .until(
      has("station", "code", "XYZ")
    ).path()
```

But I'm not sure how I can introduce the "gathering og announcement" requirement here. I guess I'm missing something basic about traversals. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit for clarification:

Given a starting station vertex and an ending station vertex, I'd like to find a path from start -> end. For each vertex in this path I'd also like to find any **announcement** vertex associated with it through an incomming **announcedOn** edge. The result I hope to get is:

- path: vertex -> edge -> vertex -> ... -> vertex
- announcements[]

Comment: Just to clarify, you only want to actually traverse over "travelsTo" edges, but if any of the nodes/vertices that you arrive at has an incoming "announcedOn" edge you want to fetch the properties from that node and at the end return any found? If I have that right, you will probably want to add a `sideEffect` inside the `repeat` body that does something like `sideEffect(in('announcedOn').store('announcements'))` If what I am describing sounds right I can add a longer answer below.

Comment: The ideal case would be to travel from station A to station B along "travelsTo" edges and if any vertex along the way has one or more incomming "announcedOn" edges find the corresponding "announcement" node at the other end. And finally, if possible, do not include duplicate "announcement" vertecies. Hope that makes it clearer. The end result I hope to get is the "path" (vertecies and edges) from A to B + all announcements found.

Comment: Do you want the `announcement` nodes as part of the path itself or returned alongside the path? The trickiest part of collecting them alongside the path will be knowing which path they belong to. If they are included in the path, pulling out the duplicates will be a little trickier. I added the first method as an answer below.

Comment: I'm fine with doing it in multiple steps if needed. The core requirement is to fetch the announcement vertecies, but it would be incredibly useful to have the path that these announcements resulted from for debugging and verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having sample data means that this is untested but I think the query will need to be along these lines:

```java
g.V().
  has("station", "code", "ABC").
  repeat(out("travelsTo").           
         sideEffect(in('announcedOn').store('announcements')).simplePath()).
  until(has("station", "code", "XYZ")).
  union(path().fold(),cap('announcements').dedup(local))
```

The only downside of this approach is that the 'announcements' are not tied to a given path.

Comment: Wow, this worked right away. I need to read up on `sideEffect()`. I also don't think the `dedupe()` step is required since `simplePath()` will eliminate known vertecies. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `simplePath` only affects the actual path taken itself. So anything done inside the `sideEffect` step is invisible to `simplePath`. In other words, you will probably want to keep the `dedup`.

Comment: Understood, the data may be deduped in the visual graph produced by my IDE (gdotv) then, because it did not appear twice there. I'll check out the raw data. Thanks!